# Can`t get permissions for user birthday to our app

Tags: facebook, permissions, date

We`ve got an app.
When we configured permissions needed for our app we choose user_birthday.
 [image]

After we press the "Preview Login Dialog" - we can see this 
here [image]
The red selection is the user birthday

But, when user try to connect to our app he see 
here  [image]
There is no birthday permissions there.

So, as the result we can`t get the user_birthday param.
What are we doing wrong?

Comment: here is the third link  [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5qk22.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions that you specify inside the facebook app settings are just for when users install your app from the Facebook App Center.

To get user permissions when users sign into your app, you need to request them during the authentication process.

You can find all the information you need here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/canvas-games/authenticate/

Comment: Thanks man. This really helps me to find bug in code, instead of tries to find errors in FB :).
P.S. Sorry i can`t vote +1 to your helpful post, because of reputation.

Comment: You should be able to accept it as being correct, glad I could help :)